# making an openGL texture image clickable in android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have an texture which is created using openGL. Now I want to make it click able that when someone tap on that texture image it should fire an event. How can I do this or is it not possible??

Answer (score 0):

Have an Activity with `GLSurfaceView` in it. The `GLSurfaceView` will then be attached to your `renderer` : `mGLView.setRenderer(theRenderer);`, and you can keep touch screen interactions in your Activity with `public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event)`